# For Statement: compile error

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm getting a compile error for line 34. I've tried setting the variable to equal itself and that fixes the compile error, but it doesn't run the program correctly.

Here is the error:

```
BaseConverter.java:34: error: illegal start of expression
                    for(iCount=; iCount>=0; iCount--)
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class BaseConverter
{
public static void main(String []args)
{
    Scanner Keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    int iConvertNum;
    int iFromBase;
    int iToBase;
    int iCount;
    int iQuotent=0; 
    int[] iRemander= new int[100];

    System.out.print("Enter the positive integer you want to convert: ");
    iConvertNum=Keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\nEnter the base you are converting from(1-16): ");
    iFromBase=Keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\nEnter the base you are converting to(1-16): ");
    iToBase=Keyboard.nextInt();

    //if(iFromBase<iToBase)
    //{
        for(iCount=0; iQuotent>0; iCount++)
        {
            iRemander[iCount]=iConvertNum/iToBase;
            iQuotent=(iConvertNum/(iToBase+iRemander[iCount]));
            iConvertNum=iQuotent;

            //return iRemander[iCount];
        }
    iCount-=1;
        for(iCount; iCount>=0; iCount--)
        {
            System.out.print(iRemander[iCount]);
        }

    /*  
    }
    else if(iFromBase>iToBase)
    {
    }
    else(iFromBase==iToBase)
    {
    }
    */
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is it: `for(iCount=; iCount>=0; iCount--)` with an `=` as you have in the compiler error message, or `for(iCount; iCount>=0; iCount--)` without an `=` as you have in your code?

Comment: it is without. I apologize. I was trying to make changes and didn't recompile my program after changing the code to what you see above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line

```
for(iCount; iCount>=0; iCount--)
```

is illegal in Java, because it must be a statement, and `iCount` by itself isn't a statement.  If you don't want to change the value of `iCount`, then leave the first part of the `for` loop blank:

```
for( ; iCount>=0; iCount--)
```

Even if you really had `for(iCount=; iCount>=0; iCount--)`; that would not compile because the statement isn't complete.  But because you specifically established a value for `iCount` before this particular `for` loop, I still think it should be a blank first statement in that `for` loop.

Comment: Look at the compile error - the OP appears not to have actually written the code that they claim to have written.

Comment: @DavidWallace I've asked the OP which it is, because the error message is inconsistent with the code given.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm having another problem now. The program isn't running my for loops. I have no idea why.

Comment: In the first `for` loop, you initialize `iCount` to `0`, but your condition is `iQuotent > 0`, which is `false`, so that `for` loop has no iterations.  You will want it to initialize `iQuotent` to be something greater than 0 before the first `for` loop starts.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, you wrote `for(iCount=; iCount>=0; iCount--)`.  There needs to be be some expression after the first `=`, for `iCount` to start at.